# If/Else OR "? :" (conditional) not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Trying to rephrase/clean up question here:**

I'm trying to do some sort of conditional statement to calculate a value. To mock my data I am assigning the value in my controller (temporarily) to see how my UI is coming along. I can perform the calculation in a function block in the view, but it's lengthy and doesn't belong there. So, I am trying now to do the calculation in a model (`Calculations.cs`).

The code for the calculation is working in that a value is being passed, except that my condition is failing and passing the default value of `0` when it should be passing another value based on my mocked value in the controller.

Here is the `Calculations.cs`

```
public class Calculations
{
    PriceQuote price = new PriceQuote();
    StepFilingInformation filing = new StepFilingInformation();
    public decimal Chapter7Calculation
    {
        get
        {
            return
                price.priceChapter7
                +
                ((filing.PaymentPlanRadioButton ==
                    Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes)
                ?
                price.pricePaymentPlanChapter7
                :
                0);
        }

    }
}
```

I originally had `(filing.PaymentPlanRadioButton == Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes)` checking whether or not the radio button was set to "Yes", but changed it to `ReferenceEquals`. This doesn't affect the outcome.

I have my controller assigning the value to `PaymentPlanRadioButton` to "Yes", so `pricePaymentPlanChapter7` should be the value being added to `priceChapter7`, but it is not. Instead "0" is being added as the fall back to the condition.  So `PaymentPlanRadioButton` is null even though I am assigning it in the controller.

I cannot figure out how to fix this. If I assign it in the model and get it to work that will not resolve the issue as when I remove the mocking controller and expect a user to choose a radio button it will still be `null` and the condition will fail.

Here is the "mock" controller:

```
public class QuoteMailerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult EMailQuote()
    {
        Calculations calc = new Calculations();
        var total = calc.Chapter7Calculation;

        QuoteData quoteData = new QuoteData
        {
            StepFilingInformation = new Models.StepFilingInformation
            {
                //"No" is commented out, so "Yes" is assigned
                //PaymentPlanRadioButton = 
                    //Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.No,
                PaymentPlanRadioButton = 
                    Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes,
            }
         };
    }
}
```

And this is where I store prices (`PriceQuote.cs`):

```
public class PriceQuote
{
    public decimal priceChapter7 { get { return 799; } }
    public decimal pricePaymentPlanChapter7 { get { return 100; } }
}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class QuoteData
{
    public PriceQuote priceQuote;
    public Calculations calculations;
    public StepFilingInformation stepFilingInformation { get; set; }
    public QuoteData()
    {
        PriceQuote = new PriceQuote();
        Calculations = new Calculations();
    }
}
```

So, the way this should work is 799 + 100 = 899, since `PaymentPlan.Yes` is assigned as the value to the radio button in the controller. But instead I am getting just 799 (799 + 0) because when I debug `PaymentPlanRadioButton` is coming up null.

Any thoughts/guidance?

Just in case, here is the `PaymentPlanRadioButton` located within `StepFilingInformation.cs` (and is one of my models):

```
public enum PaymentPlan
{
    No,
    Yes
}
public class PaymentPlanSelectorAttribute : SelectorAttribute
{
    public override IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
    {
        return Selector.GetItemsFromEnum<PaymentPlan>();
    }
}       
[PaymentPlanSelector(BulkSelectionThreshold = 3)]
public PaymentPlan? PaymentPlanRadioButton { get; set; }
```

Sorry for the length.

**FOR CONTEXT THIS IS WHAT I WAS TRYING TO GET OUT OF DOING**

I originally had this calculation code in a function block in my view. The calculation works fine there, but obviously very lengthy and not appropriate.

This is what my function block looked like (partially)

```
@{ Model.PriceQuote.calculationChapter7
    =
    Model.PriceQuote.priceChapter7
    +
    ((Model.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlanRadioButton == 
        StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.No)
    ?
    Model.PriceQuote.priceNoPaymentPlan
    :
    Model.PriceQuote.pricePaymentPlanChapter7)
    +
    ...//more of the same
    ;
}
```

So I've been struggling to get this into a `.cs` file.

Comment: Are you sure that your model data is being input into the controller correctly?  The ?: will not be the bug.

Comment: Check the data, that arrives. Other than that - it would help, if you could post the definitions of the enums `Price` and `MyPropertyEnum` and a stripped-down version of `MyModel` that contains the important properties (e.g. `MyProperty`)

Comment: Based on this update, the first thing to correct is the use of ReferenceEquals - this isn't an appropriate way to compare value types (the Enum in your case). It will walways return false.

Comment: Changed it back but still same problem. I tried an `if/else` statement, but same thing.

Comment: @RJLohan Added some context of what was working for me in a view (although inappropriate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adding a 2nd answer since the added code has changed significantly since the original post].

I think the root problem here is the way you have implemented your Calculations class. The Chapter7Calculation property is *always* going to return 799 + 0, because it is using private local class variables to determine what values to return;

```
public class Calculations
{
    PriceQuote price = new PriceQuote();

    // private local variable - will ALWAYS have PaymentPlanRadioButton = null
    StepFilingInformation filing = new StepFilingInformation();

    public decimal Chapter7Calculation
    {
        get {
            return
                price.priceChapter7
                +
                (filing.PaymentPlanRadioButton == Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes)
                ? price.pricePaymentPlanChapter7
                : 0);
        }
    }
}
```

You have a 'controller' modifying some **other** instance of StepFilingInformation, which your Calculations class has no awareness of. As well, your PriceQuote class is just returning constant or static values, so there's no real need to instantiate it. Modify that class like so;

```
public static class PriceQuote
{
    public static decimal PriceChapter7 { get { return 799; } }
    public static decimal PricePaymentPlanChapter7 { get { return 100; } }
}
```

Change your Calculations to a method like so;

```
public decimal CalculatePrice(QuoteData quoteData)
{
    return PriceQuote.PriceChapter7 + 
        (quoteData.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlanRadioButton == Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes) 
        ? PriceQuote.PricePaymentPlanChapter7 : 0);
}
```

And now your controller can pass in the QuoteData instance it has created, and you should see a better result.  Example code for the mock controller;

```
public class QuoteMailerController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult EMailQuote()
    {
        Calculations calc = new Calculations();

        QuoteData quoteData = new QuoteData
        {
            StepFilingInformation = new Models.StepFilingInformation
            {
                PaymentPlanRadioButton = Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes,
            }
         };

         var total = calc.CalculatePrice(quoteData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just not doing this right. I cannot get it to work. I presume that I am taking out `PriceQuote price = new PriceQuote();` and `StepFilingInformation filing = new StepFilingInformation();` from the class `Calculations.cs`. When I try to call it in the view `@Model.Calculations.CalculatePrice` I get the intellisense warning that "cannot convert method group...", so I add the `()` and try different parameters `price` and `filing` to no avail (error is they don't exist in current context). Is there any way to avoid passing parameters? I'd be passing a bunch of parameters (10 models).

Comment: Gonna offer bounty to you first.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've reworked everything to account for static (thanks for that suggestion, btw). Now I am just struggling with calling this in the view. I'm trying variations on `@Calculations.CalculatePrice` with parenthesis, without, with parameter, without, etc. Something silly I am not doing, I know. Also took out references to `PriceQuote` and `Calculations` from my ViewModel.

Comment: I THINK IT'S SOLVED! I'm going to edit your code a bit. If you can, please confirm if this is ok to do. I suspect it's not the right way, but it works. If not, I'd appreciate any alternative suggestions. It's saying I can't award bounty for 14 hours. Going to mark as answer - I think that automatically gives you bounty later.

Answer (score 3):

Have you really got this bit of code:

```
public decimal calculatingTest(MyModel MyModel)
{ ... }
```

rather than this?

```
public decimal calculatingTest(MyModel myModel) // note the difference in case.
{ ... }
```

Only that sort of thing can make life really complicated.

Comment: Concur; it's quite confusing - especially with partial code snippets - to determine the problem. There could be static fields in there confusing things.

Comment: Exactly. I've met that sort of problem in the past when debugging somebody else's code.

Comment: @RJLohan Trying not to have too large a post (clearly I have not succeeded). I updated the code. Sorry, not sure what would be relevant.

Comment: I recall confusing myself with this issue. When I did `MyModel myModel = new MyModel();` at the top `MyProperty` would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried debugging through to ensure that MyModel.MyModelProperty really does equal "No" at runtime?

If it is, perhaps you need to override the equality operator (i.e. perhaps the "==" test is failing) - see MSDN article here for a tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I was debugging and switching "No" and "Yes" and never even saw the "Yes". So if my controller is not mocking the data before the model calculation is called that would seem to be my problem. Now to try and figure out how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

In your Calculations class, you are getting '100' as a return value not because

```
MyModel.MyProperty == MyModel.MyPropertyEnum.Yes
```

but because it **doesn't** equal MyModel.MyPropertyEnum.No. So your if block is just falling to the default case. In this code snipped, MyModel.MyProperty has no value assigned, so it just takes the default, which from what I can tell is;

```
(MyPropertyEnum?)null
```

The 'not all code paths return a value' exception is due to the fact you have made MyProperty a nullable type and not provided an outcome for;

```
MyModel.MyProperty == null
```

And again, your use of type names as variable names is a poor choice. You have a class instance variable called 'MyModel' in Calculations.cs and a method argument called MyModel in calculatingTest. It is confusing.

And *lastly*, the reason for your StackOverflowException is that you are recursively calling calculatingTest with the same argument, so it gets into an infinite loop.

There's quite a few issues here which you can clean up and you'll probably find the cause of your problem.

Comment: Ok, cleaned up my code a bit. I am assigning a value in the controller for MyProperty: `MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel(); { MyModel = new Models.MyModel { MyProperty = Models.MyModel.MyPropertyEnum.No } }` So it's clear that although I am assigning in controller, the model is getting called first and not picking up the assignment. Is there particular code I need in the controller (I posted what I had in the controller in my original question). As for not providing for an outcome for `null` I was hoping I wouldn't have to if I got the code right, but will research that independently.

Comment: Just for clarity, my controller is just mocking data while I test out this stuff.  It's not permanent. The use case is user input on a form, so that the values they select will be the ones used to calculate.

Comment: Can you clean up the example code in your post? Also, I don't see how the type 'MyViewModel' is used anywhere, or what relevance it has to your question.

Comment: I've added a 2nd answer to reflect the changes you made to your original post.